# Поменять ключи и значения в массиве, чтобы можно было выводить значения по типу $array[0]?

Tags: php

Значения из $_POST я записал в массив. (это были checkbox'ы)

```
$links_array = array();
$links_array = $_POST;
foreach ($links_array as $link_num => $link_name) {/*теперь POST у нас в массиве*/}
array_pop($links_array);//убрали последнее значение
//До сюда все работает и выводит в виде:
```

> Array ( [B1_with_B1] => on [B2_with_B1] => on [B3_with_B1] => on )

**Я хочу заменить значения на цифры 0 1 2 ... и поменять ключи с значениями местами, (чтобы можно было извлекать элементы по типу $array[0]**, но если я поменяю их местами с помощью

```
array_flip($links_array);
$values = array_values($links_array);
print_r($values);
```

, то будет

> Array ( [0] => on [1] => on [2] => on )

Прошу дать подсказку к реализации вышенаписанного.

Comment: array_keys(), если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: @Ипатьев Спасибо, я почему то только array_values использовал, а про keys подумал только сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

```
$aer=array('B1_with_B1' => 'on', 'B2_with_B1' => 'on', 'B3_with_B1' => 'on');
$row=count($aer);

foreach ($aer as $key => $value) {

for ($tr=0; $tr<=$row; $tr++){

$dat[$value.$tr]=$key;

}
    }



print_r($dat);
```